# Exponential decay Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

> [image]

I managed to get part a) but when I try to use the fact that $$\cos(t\omega)=\frac{e^{it\omega}+e^{-it\omega}}{2}$$ and $$\sin(t\omega)=\frac{e^{it\omega}-e^{-it\omega}}{2i}$$
for part b), then I get a result of 0 and not ${\pi}e^{-t\lambda}$

Comment: Could you show your calculations?

Comment: Hint: $$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda \cos\omega t + \omega \sin\omega t}{\lambda^2+\omega^2} d\omega
= \operatorname{Re} \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda-i\omega}{\lambda^2+\omega^2} e^{i\omega t} \, d\omega$$

Comment: Hello, what does Re mean?
and where I am stuck is:
$$\int_0^{\inf}\frac{e^{it\omega}(i\lambda+\omega)+e^{-it\omega}(i\lambda-\omega)}{2i(\lambda^2+\omega^2)}$$

Comment: @Adam $\operatorname{Re}$ means "real part." I.e, $\operatorname{Re}(a+\mathrm{i}b)=a.$

Comment: Ok, thanks, I know what to do, instead of integrating the whole thing at once, just split it into two integrals the first with the cosine term and second with sine term, thanks very much

Comment: As Henry Lee shows (and I hinted) you do *not* need to split the integral into a cosine part and a sine part.

Answer (score 2):

notice how we have:
$$g(\omega,\lambda,t)=\frac{\lambda\cos\omega t+\omega\sin\omega t}{\lambda^2+\omega^2}$$
we know that:
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$
lets break it down and see what we have:
$$e^{i\omega t}=\cos\omega t+i\sin\omega t$$
now notice if we take:
$$(\lambda-i\omega)e^{i\omega t}=(\lambda-i\omega)\cos\omega t+(\lambda-i\omega)i\sin\omega t$$
$$=(\lambda\cos\omega t+\omega\sin\omega t)+i(\lambda\sin\omega t-\omega\cos\omega t)$$
and that is where the hint @md2perpe came from.
Obviously we now need to deal with the integral:
now we can notice that our integral is just equal to:
$$\sqrt{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\bar{f}(t)e^{i\omega t}d\omega$$
and you still need to account for it being the real part but it shouldnt be too hard

Comment: ok, thank you this helps

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\bar{f}(\omega)$ in the integral?

Comment: Does $\bar{f}$ mean the Fourier transform of $f$ or is it the complex conjugate of $f$?

Comment: it should yes, my mistake. and it means fourier transform in this case, so I should probably have used hat